# Using external jars in GWT projects (server-side)

Tags: gwt, jar

I am trying to use an external jar in a Google Web Toolkit project.

The jar is for use only on the server side. For reference it is the jbcrypt jar packaged as org.mindrot.jbcrypt.

I have included the jar in my project's build path, and eclipse finds it and resolves the BCrypt class in my project.

When I try to use the service that relies on this jar (a login service that extends RemoteServiceServlet), I get a com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException which is caused by a NoClassDefFoundError for org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.

Does the development server need the jar to be somewhere else? What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it goes in project/war/WEB-INF/lib

Comment: It's `<PROJECT>/war/WEB-INF/lib` (not `src/`) but I think that's what you meant. That way, it gets packaged properly when you deploy your project as a WAR file.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'll check it, I guess. I don't know why I held off before.